# Django Allauth signup form POSTs but no redirect, no email sent

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-allauth

This was all working fine for weeks, I haven't changed anything except taken a few fields off of the signup form (`password` which I've tried putting back and still same problem).

I'm using `Allauth` with `Django` and the generic signup form `/accounts/signup/` isn't redirecting to `verification_sent.html`.

An `email_confirm.html` is also not being sent to confirm the account.

I've set up an email backend to test on `localhost` and normally the emails come through fine via the terminal window. Now when I submit the form and `request.POST`, nothing happens.

No emails, no `verification_sent.html` page redirection.

The terminal isn't throwing any errors and says

`HTTP POST /accounts/signup/ 200`

How can I go about debugging this?

signup.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit" id='signup_button'>Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
# User signup form
class UserRegisterForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.UserRegisterForm'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS=7
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
```

Comment: please read the chat)

Comment: Okay, I've just seen this! So inefficient. I'm going to send you an email.